Problem with using/launching Anaconda Navigator on Ubuntu 24.04
am using Ubuntu 24.04.  I have installed Anaconda latest version but can't see it,use it or run it, How can I use the anaconda navigator without using command lines?

Create a .desktop file for anaconda-navigator.
Place it in ~/.local/share/applications/
And it should appear in your menu.
Its structure is similar to the following:
A tentative example of a .desktop file for anaconda-navigator would be:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Anaconda Navigator
Comment=Desktop Graphical User Interface
Exec=anaconda-navigator %F
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GraphicalUser;Utility;
StartupNotify=true
NoDisplay=false
Actions=OpenNewWindow;OpenExistingFile;

[Desktop Action OpenNewWindow]
Name=Open New Window
Exec=anaconda-navigator

[Desktop Action OpenExistingFile]
Name=Open Existing File
Exec=anaconda-navigator %U

Verify that it is installed correctly and that it starts in a terminal with the command anaconda-navigator
